# How do I make my AlertDialog display its text in monospace font?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-fonts

Here's where I display an `AlertDialog`:

```
  public void showCenteredInfoDialog(TextView _title, TextView _message)  {
    _title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    builder.setCustomTitle(_title);
    builder.setMessage(_message.getText());
    AlertDialog dialog= builder.show();

    TextView messageView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  }
```

I'd like the font to be `monospace`.

**Do I need to modify an `xml` file or can Java alone handle this?** (If Java CAN handle it, it would probably take API 21, yes?)

I wonder if adding `messageView.setFontFeatureSettings("...");` or `messageView.setTypeface(...)` with some way to refer to `monospace` would work. I can't find syntax for the String argument for `setFontFeatureSettings`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for your problem. Add it in the TextView part:

```
TextView messageView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Also is possible to change the font in XML, but i think this it's more confortable.

Hope this will help you! :)

Comment: Excellent! Very simple, very easy. THANK YOU, @rpfc!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice look at what @rpfc made for me (and it doesn't require API 21):

Method to show `AlertDialog` with a `TextView` _title and _message in `MONOSPACE` font:

```
public void showCenteredInfoDialog(TextView _title, TextView _message)  {

  _title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

  this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                                               .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                                               .setCustomTitle(_title)
                                               .setMessage(_message.getText());

  AlertDialog                        dialog= builder.show();
  TextView  messageView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            messageView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
            messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```